# c macro expansion, how to generate variable names to be used in multiple lines?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'd like to generate variable name which are unique (I use `__LINE__` for this) and it should be referred by that name later in multiple lines.

At a particular line, say line 17, i will generate a variable called `xyz_17`, then in lines below, I can refer to `xyz_17` several times. But right now I am stuck with below:

```
➜  iOS git:(master) ✗ cat macro_expansion_fun.h 
// run `gcc -E macro_expansion_fun.h` to see the expansion
#define PASTE_HELPER(a,b) a ## b
#define PASTE(a,b) PASTE_HELPER(a,b)

#define VAR_NAME PASTE(xyz, __LINE__) //at this line I needed a new variable name that is related to the __LINE__ number at this line
int VAR_NAME = 12; //then used in this line and below
VAR_NAME = 13;

➜  iOS git:(master) ✗ gcc -E macro_expansion_fun.h
# 1 "macro_expansion_fun.h"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 331 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "macro_expansion_fun.h" 2





int xyz6 = 12;
xyz7 = 13;
```

How can I make `VAR_NAME` evaluate at a particular line?

---

A bit more background of my actual problem. It is actually for an objective-c application.

```
#define XLogError(fmt, ...)  do { \
    BUGLY_LOG_MACRO(BuglyLogLevelError, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    NSLog(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    {\
        NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__];\
        if(![errorString containsString:@"Domain Code=-1009 "] && ![errorString containsString:@"Domain Code=-1001 "]){\
            NSAssert(NO, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
    }\
} while (0)
```

I wrapped `NSLog`, `BuglyLog` (aka, 3rd-party crash log service), and also `NSAssert` into a macro `XLogError`, so that in `DEBUG` build, I will assert all `NSError` in my application, **except for a few cases**, where the error indicates absence of network connection or timeout (basically not programmer error).

`XLogError` might be used multiple times in a given scope (see below). I want to store the formatted error string into a variable so I can easily enumerate all exceptional cases (the number may grow so it is more reasonable to store the formatted string into a variable first) in the `if` clause.

Usage:

```
networkCallbackBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    //some networking error
    FHTLogError(@"restful api error: %@", error);
    NSError *jsonError;
    [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:o error:&jsonError];
    FHTLogError(@"deserialization error: %@", jsonError);
}];
```

Comment: What a strange concept... I wouldn't let the compiler name my variables nor the pre-processor. IMHO, these two tools have even less fantasy than me. Why you don't name the variables by yourself e.g. `xyz_12`? May be, you have to provide some additional context i.e. explain why you want to do so.

Comment: An alternative idea: Did you consider the usage of scopes? E.g. `{ int i = 12; i = 13; }` Even if an `i` of any type exists outside the scope - it's eclipsed. You can use the same and only variable name again and again and each occurrence is a unique variable.

Comment: [What are you *actually* trying to do here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Scheff Yes, I actually worked around my problem by introducing a new scope, just like what you suggested. But my first thought was using purely macro techniques and thought it was worth asking, hence the question.

Comment: @Groo Exactly as what you described, but I just thought it was worth asking, see if c macro has this capability.

Comment: @Scheff I updated my question as to why I needed autogenerated variable names. It is not for the application itself but for defensive programming.

Comment: It's still unclear (to me at least) why you need a unique variable for each expansion? Since the macro is inside a `do {...} while(0)` block anyway there should be no variable collisions anyway, so your question is basically unrelated?

Comment: @Groo Yes. You are right. I didn't realize that I already had a block...

Answer (score 2):

`__COUNTER__` is incremented each time it is referenced in a source file, starting at 0.  So, with a little extra sugar:

```
static int xyz[];
#define BEGIN_VAR int cur
#define VAR_NAME  xyz[cur]
#define NEW_VAR cur = __COUNTER__; VAR_NAME
#define END_VAR static int xyz[__COUNTER__]

int f( int a ) {
    BEGIN_VAR;
    NEW_VAR = 12;
    VAR_NAME = 13;

    if (a < 0) {
        return VAR_NAME;
    }
    NEW_VAR = 77;
    if (VAR_NAME % a == 0) {
        VAR_NAME++;
    }
    return VAR_NAME;
}

END_VAR;
```

It isn’t ISO-C, but gcc and clang support it.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. The two lines `int VAR_NAME = 12;  VAR_NAME = 13;` should evaluate to the same varname, with `__COUNTER__ ` they would be different as they are with ` __LINE__`

Comment: Exactly as @IngoLeonhardt pointed out, this is not an answer to my question. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: After the edit, this actually seems to be what OP wanted (functionally, at least; the variables are now stored inside an array).

Comment: As @Groo pointed out in the comments of my question, my actual problem is actually invalid as I overlooked the fact that I already have a outermost block for each `XLogError`. Put my mistake aside, the updated answer is not a direct answer to my question though it solves the problem. Maybe c macro never supports such functionality. So I may not mark it as an answer but I voted it.